# C# definition for IStemmer interface from Windows Search

Tags: c#, pinvoke, windows-search

Can anyone help me with translating COM IStemmer interface definition to C# or suggest tool to do that? I searched in Google and at pinvoke.net and was unable to find C# signatures.

The interface definition is the following:

```
interface IStemmer {
    HRESULT GetLicenseToUse(
       [out]  WCHAR const **ppwcsLicense
    );  

    HRESULT Init(
       [in]   ULONG ulMaxTokenSize,
       [out]  BOOL pfLicense
    );

    HRESULT GenerateWordForms(
        [in]  WCHAR const *pwcInBuf,
        [in]  ULONG cwc,
        [in]  IWordFormSink *pWordFormSink
    );
}

interface IWordFormSink {
    HRESULT PutWord(
        [in]  const WCHAR *pwcInBuf ,
        [in]  ULONG cwc
    );

    HRESULT PutAltWord(
        [in]  const WCHAR *pwcInBuf ,
        [in]  ULONG cwc
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following interface

```
[ComImport]
[Guid("EFBAF140-7F42-11CE-BE57-00AA0051FE20")]
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
public interface IStemmer
{
    void Init([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] int ulMaxTokenSize, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)] out bool pfLicense);
    void GenerateWordForms([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string pwcInBuf,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] int cwc,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)] IWordFormSink pStemSink);
    void GetLicenseToUse([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] out string ppwcsLicense);
}
```